# Upload screenshots to google cloud storage bucket with Fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, google-cloud-storage, mern

I am currently using multer to upload videos to my google storage bucket, and fluent-ffmpeg to capture thumbnails of the videos. Videos are being uploaded into the buckets correctly, but not the thumbnails from ffmpeg. How can I change the location of the thumbnails to my google storage bucket?

**Back-End Video upload**

```
require ('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const multerGoogleStorage = require('multer-google-storage');
const { Video } = require("../models/Video");
const {User} = require("../models/User")
const { auth } = require("../middleware/auth");


var storage = multer({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'videos/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`)
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
        if (ext !== '.mp4' || ext !== '.mov' || ext !== '.m3u' || ext !== '.flv' || ext !== '.avi' || ext !== '.mkv') {
            return cb(res.status(400).end('Error only videos can be uploaded'), false);
        }
        cb(null,true)
    }
})
// Set location to google storage bucket
var upload = multer({ storage: multerGoogleStorage.storageEngine() }).single("file")

router.post("/uploadfiles", (req, res) => {

    upload(req, res, err => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({sucess: false, err})
        }
        return res.json({ success: true, filePath: res.req.file.path, fileName: res.req.file.filename})
    })
});
```

**Back-end thumbnail upload**

```
router.post("/thumbnail", (req, res) => {

    let thumbsFilePath = "";
    let fileDuration = "";

    ffmpeg.ffprobe(req.body.filePath, function (err, metadata) {
        console.dir(metadata);
        console.log(metadata.format.duration);

        fileDuration = metadata.format.duration;
    })


    ffmpeg(req.body.filePath)
        .on('filenames', function (filenames) {
            console.log('Will generate ' + filenames.join(', '))
            thumbsFilePath = "thumbnails/" + filenames[0];
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('Screenshots taken');
            return res.json({ success: true, thumbsFilePath: thumbsFilePath, fileDuration: fileDuration })
        })
        //Can this be uploaded to google storage?
        .screenshots({
            // Will take 3 screenshots
            count: 3,
            folder: '/thumbnails/',
            size: '320x240',
            //Names file w/o extension
            filename:'thumbnail-%b.png'
        });
});
```

**Front-end video upload**

```
 const onDrop = (files) => {
        let formData = new FormData();
        const config = {
            header: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        }
        console.log(files)
        formData.append("file", files[0])

        axios.post('/api/video/uploadfiles', formData, config)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    let variable = {
                        filePath: response.data.filePath,
                        fileName: response.data.fileName
                    }
                    setFilePath(response.data.filePath)

                    //Thumbnail
                    axios.post('/api/video/thumbnail', variable)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (response.data.success) {
                                setDuration(response.data.fileDuration)
                                setThumbnail(response.data.thumbsFilePath)
                            } else {
                                alert("Failed to generate a thumbnail");
                            }
                        })

                } else {
                    alert('Failed to save video to the server')
                }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage#application_code) you can find the sample code of an application web page prompting the user to supply a file to be stored in Cloud Storage. The code is configuring bucket using environment variables and creates a new blob in the bucket to upload the file data.

I hope this information helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to just move them after they're generated with ffmpeg.

For example, I'm writing them to a temp directory outputted by ffmpeg, and then moving after to a Cloud Storage bucket in my cloud function:

```
    const uploadResult = await bucket.upload(targetTempFilePath, {
      destination: targetStorageFilePath,
      gzip: true
    });
```

Not sure which environment you're using (flex, cloud run, etc) but these were the instructions I was referencing, and are generally the same steps you'll want to follow: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions